# Geoserver heatmap not rendered correctly

Tags: google-maps, heatmap, geoserver

I am displaying a heatmap generated with geoserver on my google map.
It work pretty fine but the heatmap is tiled, even if the call to the wms is specifically "tiled=false".

Geoserver doc say "Rendering transformations may not work correctly in tiled mode, unless they have been specifically written to accomodate it."

The style to create heatmap in geoserver is copied from https://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/styling/sld/extensions/rendering-transform.html#heatmap-generation

The overlap in my js script is something like

```
    var url = "http://localhost:8080/geoserver/test/wms?";
    url += "&service=WMS";           //WMS service
    url += "&version=1.1.0";         //WMS version
    url += "&request=GetMap";        //WMS operation
    url += "&layers=test%3Aglobal_points"; //WMS layers to draw
    url += "&styles=heatmap";               //use default style
    url += "&format=image/png";      //image format
    url += "&TRANSPARENT=TRUE";      //only draw areas where we have data
    url += "&srs=EPSG:4326";         //projection WGS84
    url += "&bbox=" + bbox;          //set bounding box for tile
    url += "&width=256";             //tile size used by google
    url += "&height=256";
    url += "&tiled=false";
```

So, there's a way to fix it?

[image: Tiled]

Answer (score -1):

You are requesting tiles:

```
url += "&bbox=" + bbox;          //set bounding box for tile
url += "&width=256";             //tile size used by google
url += "&height=256";
```

even if you set `tiled=false` - make a request for the whole map and with width and height set to the size of the window.

Even then your heat map will change on each move of the map as more or less points come into view, if you must use a heat map then calculate it once for the whole data set and serve it as a raster layer.

Here is your obligatory XKCD on heatmaps:

[image: https://xkcd.com/1138/]